# Twitter in Django

Tags: django, web-applications, twitter, content-management-system

I have to create web application similar to twitter with a few tweaks using django. I am clueless if I have to use a CMS for this or any other existing django-application. Working from ground up is quite tedious to be honest. Can anyone recommend me which CMS( or anything else) I should attempt trying?

Comment: “I have to create web application similar to Twitter with a few tweaks using django.” Please accept my sympathies. “Working from ground up is quite tedious to be honest.” I’m sure the Twitter guys found it tedious too :) There was a Twitter competitor, [Pownce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pownce), that implemented at least it's web presence using Django, but I don’t think they ever released their source code after shutting down.

Comment: Twitter itself was originally built using Ruby on Rails using (I think) a CMS approach, but that was found to not scale well with lots of users — see e.g. http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster. I’m not sure if you’ll run into the same sorts of problems, but treating a Twitter-like service as a CMS may not be the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called trillr1. According to its page:
"Trillr is a Twitter-like microblogging service enhanced with user directory and group discussion features. "  that's maybe what you want.

https://contributions.coremedia.com/trillr1

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the closest you can come with an out-of-the-box software to imitate Twitter is [Status.net](http://status.net/open-source), the software, that powers [identi.ca](http://identi.ca). However, this is a PHP application.

I'm not aware of something similar in the Django world.